# Using an array in a do....while statement

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to use a do...while loop that loops based on the id's in my array.  I am a little new to using the do while loop, so am having some trouble incorporating the array into the thing.  Here is my relevant code:

```
    String studentId   = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID"));
    String studentId1  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID1"));   
    String studentId2  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID2"));
    String studentId3  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID3"));
    String studentId4  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID4"));
    String studentId5  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID5"));
    String studentId6  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID6"));
    String studentId7  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID7"));
    String studentId8  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID8"));
    String studentId9  = StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("Student_ID9"));


    String[] studentArray;
    studentArray = new String [15];
        studentArray[0]  = studentId;          studentArray[1]  = studentId1;
        studentArray[2]  = studentId2;         studentArray[3]  = studentId3;
        studentArray[4]  = studentId4;         studentArray[5]  = studentId5;
        studentArray[6]  = studentId6;         studentArray[7]  = studentId7;
        studentArray[8]  = studentId8;         studentArray[9]  = studentId9;


do {
    // blah blah blah
} while (  // Here is where I want to tell it to loop for every student in my array.  It should not run for id's that are empty strings(*if possible));
```

See comments for a more clear explanation.  The *StringUtils.defaultString* that is used when i am getting my parameters will give me an empty string if the param receives a *NULL*.  So if possible I would like to take that into account, and not run my "do {}" statements when the particular array ID is an empty string.  Thanks in advance for the help, and if you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: Why specifically a do...while loop? This could easily be done with a foreach loop

Comment: It would be better to use a for loop here.

Comment: @fge yes, I believe that a for each loop would work as well, I was just curious how a do while might work, but using an array in for each loop is still a problem for me.

Comment: `studentArray.length` will tell you how many elements are in the array.  It's easier to iterate over the array with `for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++)`, but you can simulate that with `do/while` if you keep and "manually" increment/test your own index variable.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you for the tips, it makes since to do a for loop now that i see it written out, Idk why the array was tripping me up so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is better done using a for each loop:

```
for(String x:studentArray){
  // do what you want to do with x
}
```

To skip over values that are null, just insert an if check at the beginning of the loop and continue if x is empty.

Comment: @mak - 'x' can never be null as the OP is pre-processing it already

Answer (score 4):

Using [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) is simple

```
for(String student: studentArray)
{
  if(!student.equals(""))
  {
    //process data
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** The if condition can also be written as `!"".equals(student)` but it is not necessary in your scenario as you are already making sure the id's are never `null` by using `StringUtils.defaultString`

Answer (score 4):

The only difference between a `do...while` loop and a `while` loop is that the former is **always executed at least once**.

With that in mind, we can write code as if we were writing a standard `while` loop, keeping in the back of our minds that this loop will run through at least once.

```
int i = 0; // Some counter to keep track of the index position
do {
    if(!(studentArray[i] == null || studentArray[i] == "")) {
        // Good stuff here
    }
    i++;
} while(i < studentArray.length);
```

Comment: You forgot to check if the array is empty.

Comment: If one initializes the array, at worst its base value will be `""`.  If one assigns values into the array, at worst its base value will be `null`, `0`, or `false`.  I work form the assumption (and intent of the original code) that the array is not empty, but you are otherwise *absolutely right*.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
if (studentArray.length > 0) {
    do {
        doSomethingWithArrayElement(studentArray[i]);
        i++;
    } while (i < studentArray.length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        string[] arr = new string[4]; // Initialize
        arr[0] = "one";               // Element 1
        arr[1] = "two";               // Element 2
        arr[2] = "three";             // Element 3
        arr[3] = "four";              // Element 4

        // Loop over strings
        foreach (string s in arr)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

        // do while
        var aValue = "Not Empty";
        do
        {
            //loop through elements here
            for (int a = 0; a < arr.Length; a++)
            {
                aValue = arr[a];
            }

        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aValue));
```

Comment: C# may be *like* Java, but it isn't *exactly* Java.  It also seems that you've missed the point of the `do...while`; it seems that, if the last element is empty in the array, it will terminate, but not a step before.

Answer (score -1):

---

> This a sample code using arrays This Program Uses Do.... While Loop to
> Loop over a whole program when there is a user prompt.

---

```
package doWhileLoop;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class doWhileLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //this is a program to prompt a user to continue or pass using the do while loop
        String programCounter;
        do {
            int sum=0;
            int list[] = new int[3];
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter  3 numbers to be added: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                list[i] = in.nextInt();
                sum+= list[i];
            }
            System.out.println("sum = "+ sum);

            System.out.println("Enter Yes to continue or No to exit........");
            programCounter = in.next();

        }
        while (programCounter.equals("yes"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - how is this related to the given question?